# ASMX Web Service - not getting a reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio, asmx

I've got a website that interacts with a web service via Web Reference - no problem.

Now I'm building a console application in the same solution, that also needs to access that web service.

I used: Add->Service Reference->Advanced-Web Reference. I type in the URL of the service.asmx and a name. This is what I get:

[image: Web reference]

When I try reference that in the code, I get this:

[image: Code error]

I can't seem to interact with that namespace/reference.

In my website, I did practically the same thing, adding the reference:

[image: Reference in web site]

Then I used it fine:

[image: working code]

I see in the console app, there's a difference file hierarchy (Reference.map file) than in the website. The only difference I'm aware of is that I added the website service in an older Visual Studio version, than I'm working with now. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look in reference.cs to check the namespace of the generated proxy.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyChu - I'm using a different namespace in the console app, so the code I copied was using the website's namespace. You want to create an answer and I'll accept it? (Can't believe I wasted 2 hours on that...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# code for the web service client proxy is generated in `Reference.cs`. You can open it to see what namespace it's in.